# Tag Editor Now Supports Inline Autocomplete

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Just FYI, thanks to the ever-so-awesome [Jörn Zaefferer](http://bassistance.de/), we have an updated tag intellisense / autocomplete dropdown that **works for tags in the middle as well as at the end**.

Prior to this update, the tag intellisense dropdown only worked for the *last* tag in the text box.

I searched and searched (even with Google!) and could not find an open bug on this, although I swore I saw one, at one point..

What other improvements make sense for the tag editor?

Comment: Google loves me this I know, because the Google told me so.

Comment: I like      it!

Comment: Nice!  I had submitted this feature request on uservoice a while back.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to see a confirmation when a user is creating new tags (or using empty tags) along these lines:

> You are creating a new tag: *[tag-name]*. Please make sure that no similar tags already exist and that the tag is spelled correctly. *[maybe a list of similar tags, too]*

Because it *is* a problem, even if it isn't a large one. A significant portion of new tags are typos or unhyphenated versions of existing tags. Anything that can draw attention to this at the source of new tags would help.

Answer (score 5):

There's already code that runs in the background that automatically merges certain known synonyms.  It would be nice to see this happen at the time the tags are used instead, so that posts are correct in the first place rather than waiting for a the background process or an editor to catch up with them.