# Tag suggestion only works for the first tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, opera, internet-explorer, tag-autocomplete

I don't know why, but the last few days I haven't gotten any tag suggestions other than for the first one I type in. I have had to write one, cut it out, write another, paste the other one in, cut bot out, type the third one, paste the other two in, and so on.

I have the same problem in both Opera 9.64 and IE 8 on Vista.

Comment: A fix requires the browser specific code to read the cursor position in the input field. The method currently implemented seems to work only for FF/Safari.

Answer (score 6):

I've updated the autocomplete plugin with some more IE-specific code, which seems to work for Opera, too. Please give it a try: http://bassistance-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js

edit: this is now deployed

Comment: this is now deployed. tested in IE, works, Opera works but is a little quirky, which is.. well, Opera in a nutshell.

Comment: @Jeff: Wow. Now works on my machine.

Comment: often on IE7 it overrights the wrong tag when I choose a tag from the list.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing the same right now across SOFU.

Only the first tag is suggested. All others, no  matter front, middle or back, will not offer tag suggestions.

Even with a cleared and flushed cache.

**Opera 9.63**

#### Since the recent deployment...

Doesn't matter where or which number tag you're trying to put in, first or third or fifth, whenever retagging a few posts on SuperUser, the cursor will **always** jump back to the first position and replace whatever is the first word. Annoying when trying to create even a sensible list of just three tags.

Doesn't feel like proper behaviour at all.

#### Workaround for Opera

One way to deal with this in Opera is to type the tags backward.

Type in one and when you're done, hit <kbd>Home</kbd> or whatever your keyboard of choice does to get you back to the start of the input area. Then type a space and go back again to the front of the input. Now type up the next tag and it will suggest it and prefill it properly. Return to the front and pad with that leading space for each tag you want to include

Comment: Yeah, status-reproduced in Opera 9.64 OSX

Comment: status-reproduced in Opera 9.64 Windows 2000, will check under linux at home.

Comment: Same problem here (opera 9.64/Ubuntu 9.04), very annoying. Thanksfully it's very easy to disable javascript in Opera, so I can type the tags, but I don't have the suggestions.

Comment: Confirmed     .

Answer (score 1):

Response from [Jörn Zaefferer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133207/jorn-zaefferer) (the author):

> Well, in this case its just the **browser-specific code that is missing
>   to read the cursor position in the text input**, as mentioned in my
>   previous mail.
>
> I'm sure there is some obscure way to solve that in IE; not idea about
>   Opera. Maybe ask on Stackoverflow about that?

Are there any Q's on SO about this?

Answer (score 0):

When have you tried this? [The feature was fixed sometime yesterday.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12561/tag-editor-now-supports-inline-autocomplete)

**Edit:**
The functionality you describe is not related to the newly fixed tag completion. Previously it would auto-complete only the last tag in the box, which is different than *only* completing the first. In either case, try it again today.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (SO & MSO, FF 3.5.2)...