# Bug: Tag autocomplete stopped working for all tags except the first one on IE6 and IE7

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag suggestion only works for the first tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/tag-suggestion-only-works-for-the-first-tag)

Tags autocomplete now works strangely: the first tag is accompanied with autocomplete suggestions, but all the other tags are not accompanied - when I type them nothing happens at all.

The problem arises on IE 6.0.2900.5512.xpsp_sp3gdr.090206-1234 on WinXP and Win2k3. Also arises on IE 7.0.6000.15386 on Vista. Doesn't arise in Firefox 1.5.0.3

Started arising about one week ago. Arises on all trilogy sites and meta.

Comment: Does this work with later versions of IE? If so, then it's probably a very low priority fix.

Comment: At least it is reproduced with IE7. Updated the question.