# Tag completion is broken for multiple tags

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag suggestion only works for the first tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/tag-suggestion-only-works-for-the-first-tag)

Repro steps:

1. add a tag to a question.  I chose
   bug for this question.
2. add another tag.  I chose tags for
   this question.
3. Select with mouse (or enter) the
   second tag from the autocomplete
   list.

Expected behavior:
I would have 2 tags.  In this case, bug tags.

Observed behavior:

The new tag replaces the original one.  In this case I have: tags tags.

I have seen this behavior on all three sites.

This is with IE8 on Win7 if that happens to be relevant.

Comment: Agree. The linked "duplicate" has pretty much nothing to do with the behavior described.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed on FireFox 3.5 (I noticed this as far back as 1-2 weeks ago, but not certain of the exact start of this behavior)