# Why is there a "programming" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I happened to notice that Jon Skeet just got awarded a silver tag badge for [**programming**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/142/programming). Not that I mean to deny Jon yet another badge, but why does this tag need to exist? is it to balance out all the questions tagged **not-programming-related**? Questions on SO are supposed to be about programming, so this appears to be a redundant tag.

Comment: Only Jon Skeet could get a badge in programming. Just... programming.

Answer (score 15):

People, for some reason, make and use stupid and obvious tags like `programming`, `help`, `question`, etc. Probably because they don't understand tags. Likewise, we have tags like `one`, `2000`, `in` and `the` ([I complain about those in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/tighten-up-tag-restrictions-and-add-warnings-for-new-and-low-usage-tags)). Some people just don't "get" tags. I call this kind of person TheTXI.

And if you answer a lot of questions like Mr Skeet you end up getting a lot of upvotes in stupid tags. The badge mechanism isn't sentient, so it doesn't know that the tags it's making badges for are stupid. That's how Jon got a programming badge on a programming site.

Comment: In their defense, how can ponies be expected to understand tagging? And do they even need tags when they have such beautiful, luxurious flowing manes?

Comment: @Jeff @wood: Yes. Yes they do.

Comment: I feel it important to mention that Guffa is the point leader on the `question` tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=question&sort=stats&pagesize=50 Arguably, this is the most important tag on any question and answer site.

Answer (score 0):

You get special badges for upvotes in the different tags

[Check it yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of how the process works. My question is about the *tag itself*, not the process of being awarded badges for tags.

Comment: It's automatic, there's no specific control over what tag gets a badge and what doesn't

Comment: what = which....

Comment: Oh, seeing Gargamel's answer I now know what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I don't know, there's some real gems in that [programming] tag...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774027/how-do-you-program-closed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276/what-are-the-most-common-things-you-should-be-able-to-do-in-a-programming-languag

Comment: That is because programming is hard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305252/programming-is-hard-closed , time for some

Comment: Oh man those are great.

Comment: Programming is hard. Let's go shopping!